# MySQL join query is not working

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am working with CodeIgniter and MySQL. I have job_post table that looks like below :

[image]

Here I have write query like this :

```
select jp.*,u.first_name,u.last_name,group_concat(DISTINCT s.skill) as sk,group_concat(DISTINCT c.name) as ct,ufj.fav_id,ufj.is_favourite 
from job_post as jp 
left join industry as ind on ind.ind_id = jp.industry_id 
left join city c ON(FIND_IN_SET(c.city_id, jp.city) > 0) 
left join skill s ON(FIND_IN_SET(s.skill_id, jp.skill) > 0) 
join users as u on u.user_id = jp.emp_id 
left join user_favourite_job as ufj on ufj.job_id = jp.job_id and ufj.user_id = 8 
where jp.city in (2) and jp.is_delete = 1 group by job_id
```

When I have pass city id as 1 at `jp.city in (1)` than it gives perfect result but when I have pass city id as 2 at `jp.city in (2)`.

So what should I have to change in my query ?

Note : When I passed city id 2 than it display first and last record. But right now its not working.

Comment: may be the id not matching plz check your ids

Comment: use jp.city like '%2%' as in will not give proper result

Comment: saving comma separate is not good use one to many relationship

Comment: @Kool-Mind if i have multiple id then what should I have to do ? like query is not work when I have write jp.city like '%1,2%'.

Comment: den in such case use like '%1%2%' but remember it will work till 9 digit for 11,12 it will fetch the 1,2 's record

Comment: like and not like too u can use if row consist 1,11,2,12 i.e like '%1%' and not like '%11%' hope you understood

Comment: 1. See normalisation. 2. Normalise your schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USe c.city_id instead of using jp.city in where Clause.

```
select jp.*,u.first_name,u.last_name,group_concat(DISTINCT s.skill) as sk,group_concat(DISTINCT c.name) as ct,ufj.fav_id,ufj.is_favourite 
from job_post as jp 
left join industry as ind on ind.ind_id = jp.industry_id 
left join city c ON(FIND_IN_SET(c.city_id, jp.city) > 0) 
left join skill s ON(FIND_IN_SET(s.skill_id, jp.skill) > 0) 
join users as u on u.user_id = jp.emp_id 
left join user_favourite_job as ufj on ufj.job_id = jp.job_id and ufj.user_id = 8 
where c.city_id in (2) and jp.is_delete = 1 group by job_id
```

Answer (score 1):

update where clause

```
 where jp.city like '%2%'  and jp.is_delete = 1
```

or use below if it contains 1,2 and 11,12 ,etc

```
where jp.city like '%1%2%' and jp.city not like '%11%12%'  and jp.is_delete = 1
```

but using it's not optimal, so please keep id's as one to many relationshiop